# Why is my mysqli code not able to stop redundant entries from being placed in my database?

Tags: mysqli

I have been spending hours trying to figure out why I can't get my code to prevent duplicate files from going into my database. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['Register'])) 
    {
        session_start();

        $sql=mysql_query("SELECT UserName FROM BD WHERE UserName='$UName'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($sql)>=1)
        {
            echo"name already exists";
        }
        else
        {
            $FName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['FirstName']);
            $LName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['LastName']);
            $Email = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['Email']);
            $UName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST["UserName"]);
            $PW = $con->real_escape_string($_POST["Password"]);
            $sql = $con->query("INSERT INTO BD (FirstName, LastName, Email, UserName, Password) Values('{$FName}', '{$LName}', '{$Email}', '{$UName}','{$PW}')");

            header('Location: login.php');

        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

first check if your session is working properly....use 'echo $UName;' in above  code if it display anything...

Answer (score 0):

it seems you are asking for mysqli(the improved version of mysql) but you are actually using old mysql_query and mysql_num_rows command.. try replacing them with mysqli_query and mysqli_num_rows with right syntax and see if it works..

Comment: I changed the one line of my code to the following and it still doesn't stop duplicate entries. Any suggestions? Thanks!
         $sql= $con->prepare("SELECT UserName FROM BD WHERE UserName='$UName'");

Comment: Well I can see you haven't declared $UName you used in the select query for checking the username existence.... Declare it like $UName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['UserName']);